Is C++ new operator thread safe?
I'm not able to absolutely determine if the C++ new operator is thread safe. I realize that it might be vendor implementation dependent. I'm using MS Dev Studio 2022. MS docs seem to avoid the question. Public comments about it here and elsewhere are mostly educated guesses (concluding it probably is thread safe).
Does anybody know if it is? Can you point to any official MS docs discussing it?
I've tried to override the new operator in the class in which it'll be used, but the fact that it's always a static method brings with it a bunch of problems.

C++98, new is not thread safe.  (A given implementation may be thread safe, but it isn't specified in the C++98 standard.)  C++11, new is thread safe.

C++11 has official thread support, so new is inevitably thread safe. Also, check out the "Notes" section on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

@Eljay I'm not sure I'd call it like this. C++98 happily ignored threads altogether, so the burden of making everything safe was on library provider. And if your threading library made syscalls thread-unsafe... You'd likely find another threading library.

Bah. Back in the day, threads were for pansies. The REAL men used state machines and controlled their own destiny. And then along came multi-processor systems.

@Yksisarvinen • yes, granted.  The lack of thread-safety specified in C++98 was due to exactly what you said:  that C++98 didn't have threads.  Bolting on threading (like pthreads, which is what I used) had plenty of sharp edges and caveats.
